# Automatically reconnect session, if it breaks while idle, in WinSCP scripting

Tags: winscp

In WinSCP scripting, we can control the automatic retry attempts upon disconnect (just as the GUI version). The script `option reconnecttime` looks like the equivalent of *"Automatically reconnect session, if it breaks during transfer."*

My question is, what is the script equivalent for *"Automatically reconnect session, if it breaks while idle"* option in GUI?

The options are listed under the menu *"Endurance"* in settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no equivalent option in scripting to GUI option *[Automatically reconnect session, if it breaks while idle](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_pref_resume)*.

The session generally *does not go idle*, when using scripting.

Initial connection retry is also not supported in scripting. It's easy to implement it though. See [Retrying connection attempt](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_retry).